# Difference between byte flip and byte swap

Tags: c++, byte

I am trying to find the difference becoz of byte flip functionality I see in Calculator on Mac with Programmer`s view.

So I wrote a program to byte swap a value which we do to go from small to big endian or other way round and I call it as byte swap. But when I see byte flip I do not understand what exactly it is and how is it different than byte swap. I did confirm that the results are different.

For example, for an int with value 12976128

Byte Flip gives me 198;
Byte swap gives me 50688.

I want to implement an algorithm for byte flip since 198 is the value I want to get while reading something.  Anything on google says byte flip founds the help byte swap which isnt the case for me.

Comment: Convert your numbers to hex and it will be clear.  12976128=0xC60000, 198 = 0xC6, 50688=0xC600

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Byte flip and byte swap are synonyms.

The results you see are just two different ways of swapping the bytes, depending on whether you look at the number as a 32bit number (consisting of 4 bytes), or as the smallest size of a number that can hold 12976128, which is 24 bits or 3 bytes.

The 4byte swap is more usual in computer culture, because 32bit processors are currently predominant (even 64bit architectures still do most of their mathematics in 32bit numbers, partly because of backward compatible software infrastructure, partly because it is enough for many practical purposes).  But the Mac Calculator seems to use the minimum-width swap, in this case a 3 byte swap.

12976128, when converted to hexadecimal, gives you 0xC60000.  That's 3 bytes total ; each hexadecimal digit is 4 bits, or half a byte wide.  The bytes to be swapped are 0xC6, zero, and another zero.

After 3byte swap: 0x0000C6 = 198

After 4byte swap: 0x0000C600 = 50688